# How to get firestore document ID from document snapshot?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef   
                                  .limit(1)
                                  .orderBy('date')                                                                    
                                  .getDocuments();
var list = querySnapshot.documents;

querySnapshot.documents.map((document) { 
    print('Document : $document'); // not printing anything.
  });

if(list.length > 0) {
   print('ID : ${list[0].documentID}'); // not working
}
```

This is the exact code i tried...
What is the mistake in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [API documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-library.html), [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) has a [documentId](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/documentID.html) property, so I would expect this to work:

```
querySnapshot.documents[0].documentID
```

Comment: And what does it do, if not what you exepct?

Comment: You line is working!. But i tried in different way. I will update code. Please tell me what is wrong in it.

Comment: If you have a different question than the first one you asked, you should make another post, not edit your existing post.

Comment: Sorry. same question. Everything is same. Just i remove a variable to store querySnapshot before. Now i have updated, this is the code i have.

Comment: instead of `map`, i have to use `forEach`. Not sure why the list variable is not printing anything. I am using full path `querySnapshot.documents[0].documentID` Thanks for the help ..

Answer (score 6):

```
product.id
```

`documentID` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Deprecated in favor of `.id`.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

For DocumentSnapshot,
`document.id`

Comment: How does this differ from the answers already here?

Comment: It's not .documentId
It is .id

Comment: That's already been posted though, including a mention of the previous property's deprecation

Answer (score 0):

For DocumentSnapshot, 
`document.documentID`

Answer (score 0):

Also, use backticks when stringinterpolating.

```
print('ID : ${list[0].documentID}'); // not working
print(`ID : ${list[0].documentID}`); // working
```