# Firestore, get the document ID using snapshot

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I´m trying to get the collection data from firestore, and save that data in JSON format, right now I can do both and everytime there's a change my list is being updated, the problem is that it doesn´t show up the ID field, so all the collections that suffer a change are being saved without any Doc ID. I tried some of the solutions that have being suggested in the attached post but it hasn't work at all.
Any suggestion or idea that could help me.

[Get document id firestore angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373170/get-document-id-firestore-angular)

[How to get firestore document ID from document snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55113849/how-to-get-firestore-document-id-from-document-snapshot)

```
const fs =require('fs');
const db = admin.firestore();
var Notebook = db.collection('Notebook').where('itemCFE', '==', '1')
.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    if (change.type === 'modified'){
       console.log('update done',JSON.stringify(change.doc.data()));
       let data =JSON.stringify(change.doc.data());
       fs.writeFileSync('test.json', data, (err) => {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('Data Written to file');
       })
     }
   if (change.type === 'removed'){
      console.log('update done',change.doc.data());
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documents always an ID.  Inside your forEach loop, each `change` is a [DocumentChange](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentChange.html) object.  You can get the ID of the document with `change.doc.id`.

Comment: I already tried that and got the next error `TypeError: change.doc.id is not a function`

Comment: Are you putting parenthesis after "id"?  id is an object property on the DocumentSnapshot object `change.doc`, not a function. You can see from the documentation for DocumentSnapshot. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html

Comment: Yes, im putting the parenthesis  `console.log('update done',JSON.stringify(change.doc.id()));`

Comment: Don't do that.  It's a property, not a method.  Just `change.doc.id`.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, in addition to get the data of the doc through the [`DocumentChange`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange?authuser=0) by doing `change.doc.data()`, you want to get the doc ID.

You need to do `change.doc.id`, since the [`doc`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentChange?authuser=0#doc) property of a `DocumentChange` returns a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot).

Comment: I already tried that and got the next error `TypeError: change.doc.id is not a function`

Comment: Can you show the exact code that generates this error?

Comment: Sure
`D:\Upload JSON\Prueba\index.js:33
      console.log('update done',JSON.stringify(change.doc.id()));
                                                           ^

TypeError: change.doc.id is not a function
    at D:\Upload JSON\Prueba\index.js:33:60
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at D:\Upload JSON\Prueba\index.js:31:30
    `